# input:custom_modifier_name with exp:store:product_form

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I am using the product_form tag to add multiple items to the cart at one time. I am passing a category per product to a custom_modifier_name but the value is not being carried over into the cart/checkout.

```
{exp:store:product disable_form="yes" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" input:finish="Finish"}
{exp:channel:entries parse="inward" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
<div class="product-add-ons mix{categories} {category_url_title}{/categories}">
<h2>{title}</h2>
<h2>{price}</h2>
<input type="hidden" name="items[{entry_id}][entry_id]" value="{entry_id}" />
<input type="text" name="items[{entry_id}][item_qty]" id="textfield" /> Qty
{modifiers}
{if modifier_instructions}<p class="instr">{modifier_instructions}</p>{/if}
{if modifier_type == 'var' OR modifier_type == 'var_single_sku'}
<!-- select -->
<select id="{modifier_input_name}" name="items[{entry_id}][{modifier_input_name}]" style="visibility:hidden">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="{option_id}">
{option_name} {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}
</option>
{/modifier_options}
</select>
{if:else}
{modifier_options}
<input type="text" name="items[{entry_id}][{modifier_input_name}]" />
{/modifier_options}
{/if}
{/modifiers}
<input type="hidden" name="items[{entry_id}][finish]" value="{categories}{category_name}{/categories}" />
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:store:product}
```

Everything else works great except for my custom modifier. I have tried using it in and outside of the {modifiers} tags with no luck either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Danielle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the product_form tag you need to move `input:finish="Finish"` to the `{exp:store:product_form input:finish="Finish"}` tag instead of on the `{exp:store:product}` tag

Comment: Bingo. And the reason for this is that the custom inputs are encrypted and stored in the hidden `_params` field you will notice is added to your HTML form. When you use `disable_form` on the inner product tag this hidden field doesn't get added, hence why Store ignores the input.